# Clustering mixed variables in SAS

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, sas, p-value, r-squared

I have following variables in  my dataset:

1. Working hours (numerical:ordinal)
2. Effectiveness (categorical:ordinal ; 4 values-> (poor,average,good,best))
3. Satisfaction (categorical:ordinal ; 4 values-> (poor,average,good,best))

I want to cluster the data on the basis of how good is my worker. I am expecting 4-5 clusters effectively. I ran fastclus in sas after normalising my data (mean=0 std=1)

But i doubt the k means will work on categorical variables. I have getting an Rsqaure value of 62% when i have 5 clusters.

Any help on how to go about this problem?

Comment: Unless you have something unusual, working hours is better regarded as measured, not ordinal. It may be conventional to record (e.g.) integers only, but if you have say 40 hours and 20 hours for two workers, differences and ratios both make sense and you have an acceptable measurement. Age in years is a similar example: it is widely conventional to report integers, but it's a measurement too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of clustering, there is a simple graph within reach.

Form a 16-category variable from effectiveness and satisfaction. (Naturally, not all joint categories are guaranteed to be present in your data.)

Then you can plot work hours against that. If you have multiple observations with exactly the same values, that's not fatal, although something like jittering may be needed to show relative frequency.

It might be suggestive. It is also a plot on which your clusters can be mapped.

In some circumstances, it might also suggest that clustering is a bad idea, as your workers are spread out in a continuum.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use SAS but I can give you the sketch of one approach that could work when you want to cluster categorical data.

The first step is to convert `working hour` into categorical data (by dividing in class, 4 classes is ok here) and apply a Multicorrespondance Analysis (MCA) to your data.

In a second step, you can use the factorial axes from the MCA which are numerical to cluster your data.

I know how to do it with R but I'm sure that it's straightforward in SAS too.

Basically, the idea is to use factor analysis (here MCA) to transform your qualitative information into quantitative information and to cluster based on these new numerical variables representing your data.

Comment: How will factor analysis help here? Isn't k-modes clustering more meaningful here? I am very new to clustering. Would be really helpful if you throw some light on this.

Comment: Using an MCA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis) you "turn" you categorical data into numerical one by using the axes from the MCA (or component) instead of the original variable. Now using those new numerical variables (axes) you can use classical clustering techniques such as k-means. It's just one approach, surely k-mode is another way to cluster mixed data

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is **define similarity**. Pretty much all clustering algorithms require some means of similarity. K-means for example uses squared Euclidean distance as similarity measure. If this measure does not make sense for your data (or the means do not make sense), then don't use k-means.

Hierarchical clustering does not need to compute means, but you still need to define **similarity** there. So that is your first task: define similarity, then maybe try to run hierarchical clustering and draw a dendrogram to see if the data clusters.